# Ways to avoid stuttering in go package and struct names?

Tags: go

I have been doing a bit of go programming of late and while trying to follow [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) style guidelines, I sometimes find it difficult to avoid stuttering when naming packages and interfaces and structs.

As an example.
I might have a **console** package with a **Console.go** file containing a **Console** interface a **console** struct and a New function.

```
//console/Console.go
package console

type Console interface {
   Print(s String)
}

type console struct {
  ....
}

func (c *console) Print(s String){
  ....
}

func New() Console{
   return &console{}
}
```

Now when I use this somewhere I end up using a `console.Console` type everywhere.

When I have two or more structs in a package I end up things like 
`con := console.NewConsole()`

I don't mind having large mostly flat package structures but I do like to keep my code organized as much as possible.  I am ok with the idea of IO.Reader and IO.Writer but what to do when the package is the same as the thing but still needs to be separated.  *(Yes I am aware that the given example could be Console.Writer but lets pretend its something completely different)*

So my questions are:
Is this stutter effect something I should even worry about? (ie. Is it bad form?)
Does anyone have any tips in avoiding it?

Comment: You could think about naming it `Interface` like [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface). But I agree with @Adrian and as long as the constructor is `New` and not `NewConsole` you're fine

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Stuttering type names are generally fine - it's not unusual to have a `foo.Foo`, because package `foo` is dedicated to defining type `Foo`. There's absolutely nothing wrong with that.

What you want to avoid is *unnecessary* stuttering; this would be things like `foo.NewFoo` when simply `foo.New` is sufficiently precise, or `foo.FooBar` and `foo.FooBaz` where `foo.Bar` and `foo.Baz` would work just as well.

Consider the standard library's `html/template`, which defines a type (`template.Template`) and a constructor (`template.New`).

Comment: Thanks I kind of thought that I was overthinking this.